# AngularJS: Get the value of a textarea with its ID and assign it to another textare

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I can use jQuery to get the value of a textarea like this

```
<textarea id="message"></textarea>
<script type=text/javascript>
$(function() {
  $('#button').click(function() {
    var value = $('#message').val();
    alert(value);
  });
});                
</script>
<textarea id="getRetrievedValue"></textarea>
```

Please can I achieve the same purpose with angularJS and assign the value to another textarea
Thank you

Comment: Where is your angular code? Yes you can easily achieve it using angalur

Comment: In angularjs, I can use ng-model to get the value, but my challenge is using the ID property of the textarea instead of ng-model to get the value and assign it to another textarea

Answer (score 0):

ng-model do it for you, use the same ng-model:

`<textarea ng-model="textarea1"></textarea>`

`<textarea ng-model="textarea1"></textarea>`

or:

in html:

```
`<textarea ng-model="textarea1" ng-change="changeText()"></textarea>

<textarea ng-model="textarea2"></textarea>`
```

in controller:

```
$scope.changeText=function(){
$scope.textarea2=$scope.textarea1;
}
```